# Button not visible while deploying app in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout, size-classes

[image]

I developed an app for iPhone initially. But later changed the target device as "Universal". But while deploying the app in iPad, the buttons in my UIViews are not visible.

From initial R&D I came to know that it has something to do with Size classes. Can someone give me a head-start?

*With Width-Compact and Height-Any:*

[image]

*With Width-Any and Height-Any:*

[image]

Comment: Are you working with Storyboards or define the size and position with code?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of iphone and ipad ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: No..It did not... I think I am getting stuck with the Autolayout/Constraint part

Answer (score 1):

Here, some details about, Size classes allows you to design your storyboard and XIB files to run in any iOS device (all screen sizes). In size classes you have relative amount for width and height dimensions:

• Regular: think of it as BIG like the width and height in iPad or the width of iPhone 6 Plus in landscape mode.

• Compact: think of it as LITTLE like the iPhone height in landscape orientation or the iPhone width in portrait.

• Any: used when your layout doesn’t change in any screen size.

For more details, please, check following links.

https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/
https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Select your button and mark it Installed from the IBInspector, This `Installed` check will allow button to be visible across all devices.
But you may need to set constraints for this button to show properly.

[image]